# Bubble Sort algorithm visualizer app made in Svelte is giving me some weird output

Tags: javascript, sorting, svelte, bubble-sort

I'm trying to do a Bubble Sort algorithm visualizer. However the output is strange,
[This is the image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUhLW.png). You can try the app here: https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.38.3 by pasting the following code: (I know that a lot of code isn't mine but I made this for practicing Svelte)

```
<script>
import { flip } from 'svelte/animate'

const ARRAY_LENGTH = 54
var arr = Array.from(Array(ARRAY_LENGTH)).map(x=>Math.random() * 200 + 1)

function BubbleSort() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < ( arr.length - i -1 ); j++){
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
                var temp = arr[j]
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
                arr[j+1] = temp
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div>
{#each arr as item (item)}
    <div style="
                        background-color: green;
                        width: 10px;
                        height: {item}px;
                        margin: 0 1px;
                        display: inline-block;
                        "
                        animate:flip={{duration:500}}
    />
{/each}
</div>

<button on:click={BubbleSort}>
   Next
</button>
```

Comment: Most likely related to a bug in Svelte version 3.38. It works correctly in 3.37. A bug fix which likely also fixes this was merged already (release pending).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order Keyed each blocks in Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462699/how-to-order-keyed-each-blocks-in-svelte)

Comment: Version 3.39 was just released which fixes this issue. I posted this as the answer but it was hidden due to being a duplicate answer, so I marked this question as being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462699/how-to-order-keyed-each-blocks-in-svelte/68471678#68471678 instead.