# How to order Keyed each blocks in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

I've created a store with a list of users and I want to order using different parameters.

**store.js**

```js
export const users = writable([
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Kepler",
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Planck",
  },
// more users going in here
```

To do so, I'm using [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) from Lodash.

**Case A.** If I don't use a keyed each blocks then `orderBy` works as expected.

**App.svelte**

```
{#each _.orderBy($users, [param], [order]) as user}
  <div>{user.id} {user.name}</div>
{/each}
```

But then if I remove or do some specific changes to my store, the updates don't work properly. [A better explanation of what's happening in the Svelte's docs](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks).

**Case B.** If I use a keyed each block then updates work as expected but not `orderBy`.

**App.svelte**

```
{#each _.orderBy($users, [param], [order]) as user (user.id)}
    <div>{user.id} {user.name}</div>
{/each}
```

[Here a Real Example on Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3684b8d0d2364784ad92139ebe0dd8ad?version=3.38.3).

Visit link above and click on buttons to switch between ascending or descending order.

Probably I'm missing something about keyed each blocks but would like to figure out how Svelte experts solve this.

Comment: This is a bug in version 3.38, the next release will fix this

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Weird indeed. However if you have to quickly fix it a good old `.sort()` does complitely the job: https://svelte.dev/repl/e548b8072b7e4e9b936e8661af5d59d4?version=3.38.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in version 3.38. Version 3.39 was just released which fixes this issue.